# Is it possible to manage WSO2 ESB connectors in commandline?

Tags: wso2, connector, wso2-esb

I have a custom made WSO2 ESB connector. I want to automate the installation of this connector. The documentation explains how to enable the connector using the management console. Is there also a commandline interface to manage/enable connectors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable / disable a connector with an admin service (webService) called **MediationLibraryAdminService**

To see it's WSDL : `https://localhost:9443/services/MediationLibraryAdminService?wsdl`
(you must edit repository/conf/carbon.xml and change *HideAdminServiceWSDLs* to false : `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` )

Sample request to enable a connector "MyConnector" in a package "my.package" :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <xsd:updateStatus>
        <xsd:libQName>{my.package}MyConnector</xsd:libQName>
        <xsd:libName>MyConnector</xsd:libName>
        <xsd:packageName>my.package</xsd:packageName>
        <xsd:status>enabled</xsd:status>
    </xsd:updateStatus>
</soap:Body>
```

You can call this service in **command line** with **curl** : 
save above request in a file named *request.xml* and type this command line
with curl 7.40 :

```
curl --basic -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml" -k -d @request.xml https://192.168.0.33:9443/services/MediationLibraryAdminService.MediationLibraryAdminServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. I tried to port this to python, and I get a really strange error. I made another question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166603/soap-request-to-wso2-esb-soap-working-with-curl-not-with-python